# Updating the shapefile after a join

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-joins

I need to update a shapefile by joining it with a csv file in PyQGIS. This process occurs only in the memory and I want to make it permanent.

The sample code is as below:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
# Loading the layer
cities = QgsVectorLayer('C:/~/cities.shp', 'cities' , "ogr")
population =QgsVectorLayer('C:/~/population.csv', 'population' , "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([cities,population], True)

# Joining the cities with the population
info = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
info.joinLayerId = nufus.id()
# Join field name in the shp file
info.joinFieldName = "abc"
# Join field name in the csv file
info.targetFieldName = "abc"
# To increase the performance:
info.memoryCache = True
# Updating the cities shapefile 
cities.addJoin(info)
```

When I remove the population table from the layers panel, the added fields are also removed and not saved in the shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we have to save the new shapefile:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(cities, "C:/~/cities_with_population.shp", "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```